# Sending parameter with POST requests with Web-kit Form-Data with J Meter

Tags: jmeter

Trying to post a data within WebKitFormBoundary in JMeter 5.2, but getting code:406 message:Not Acceptable.

My parsed data is:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarycBh5zHV8PGTFb5LA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="heading"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json

{"headers":[{"name":"Host","value":"https://localhost:443/Country"},
{"name":"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","value":"8dc88db306d04e6d69c553499b74c5sw","secret":true}],
"httpMethod":"GET","host":"https://localhost:443/Country",
"path":"Countries/api/Countries?versionQuery=Countries_V1","scheme":"https"}
------WebKitFormBoundarycBh5zHV8PGTFb5LA--
```

I am trying post the above data from Jmeter http request in two ways: 
Method 1:

[image]

Method 2:
[image]

Snap of the browser details:
Request Header:
[image]
Form Data:
[image]

I have handled the `X-Request-Verification-Token` and `RequestVerificationToken`, which is working fine. But I am getting

```
Response message:
Embedded resource download error:https://https://localhost:443/
code:406 message:Not Acceptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way of building file upload events in JMeter is simply recording them using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just make sure to copy the file you're uploading to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, this way JMeter will be able to intercept the request and properly build the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

Check out [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) for more details if needed.

---

If you're still looking for a manual way of implementing your request the easiest option would be storing your JSON payload into `blob` file in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation and configuring the "File Upload" tab of the HTTP Request sampler to look like:

[image]

You should see something like this in the View Results Tree listener:

[image]